# Show that the dihedral group $(D_n,\circ)$ is a sub-group of $(D,\circ)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, algebraic-topology

**Question :**

> Show that the dihedral group $(D_n,\circ)$ is a sub-group of $(D,\circ)$.

**Discussion :**

In a previous part of the question, I was asked to find the group $(D,\circ)$ of the symmetries of the circle, which I found to be $O(2,\mathbb R$). So, I guess also in this question, $(D,\circ) = O(2,\mathbb R).$ In this question though, I do not understand how to proceed, so I would really appreciate a thorough explanation.

Also wanted to ask, is $(D,\circ)$ the $limit$ of $(D_n,\circ)$ at $\infty$ ?

Comment: Hint: Do you know a geometric description of $D_2$ or $D_3$ or $D_4$...?

Comment: @LeeMosher As I know, for example, $D_4$ refers to the symmetries of the tetrahedron ?

Comment: Hint: given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, how the set of $n$-th root of $1$ (in $\mathbb{C}$) can be described? Is there a geometrical description?

Comment: @CharalamposFilippatos The common geometric perspective when looking at $D_n$ is the symmetries of an $n$-gon. Think of placing inscribing an $n$-gon inside the unit circle, and see if that helps.

Comment: @AlessioRanallo $z^n = 1$ ? So we're talking about a unit circle ?

Comment: @SantanaAfton Inscribing an n-gon inside the unit circle means it's always bounded by the unit circle which it makes sence that : $(D_n,\circ) \leq (D,\circ)$ but how can I prove that strict mathematically ?

Comment: My problem is that I need guidance or a thorough explanation on how I will present this solution strict mathematically and help in understanding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big hint:

Consider the group:

$\left\langle \begin{bmatrix}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)&-\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)\\ \sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)&\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right) \end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}\right\rangle$

If we call this generating set $S= \{A,B\}$, what does $BAB^{-1} =?$

(EDIT: I get dyslexic, sometimes)

Comment: I didn't grasp the last line of the hint. By the way, as I see this group, we have an orthogonal matrix and a transformation/rotation matrix, similar to what of the group of the symmetries of the circle ?

Comment: Have you ever seen a *presentation* of $D_n$ by relations and generators? It's usually in the form: $D_n = \langle a,b: a^n = = b^2 = 1, bab^{-1} = a^{-1}\rangle$. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group. The problem asks you to verify that the group I gave you (via generators) consists of orthogonal matrices.

Comment: Understood ! What I want to ask moreover though, is how did you get this group ? What I need help with is how to present a thorough solution that is strict mathematically proven as well along with understanding the question which I'm starting to grasp now.

Comment: There are a number of ways to look at this problem: one is to view the circle and the (regular) $n$-gon as geometric objects and have these groups *act* on these objects. Note that a symmetry of the $n$-gon *also* fixes the (circumscribed) circle, which shows the inclusion. Another is using the complex plane, and using $n$-th roots of unity (and complex numbers with $|z| = 1$), along with complex-conjugation. A third way is as you started, by viewing the objects as regions of $\Bbb R^2$. From there, it helps to know that isometries are linear maps, and thus can be $2\times 2$ matrices.

Comment: Okay, got it ! Wanted to ask though because I got a little stuck, how would I proceed further to prove what I'm being asked to ?

Comment: Since $(D,\circ) \cong O(2,\Bbb R)$, is it not enough to take the determinants of the matrices I displayed? Put another way: $\det: GL(2,\Bbb R) \to (\Bbb R)^{\ast}$ is a homomorphism of groups (with kernel $SL(2,\Bbb R)$).

Comment: So, with a quick eye calculation both determinants of these matrices are equal to $1$. What does that tell me though ?

Comment: Hello again. I'm really having a hard time understanding and completing the exercise. Would it be possible for you to write a complete answer/solution ? I've spent almost the entire afternoon but I can't seem to grasp it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68304/discussion-between-david-wheeler-and-charalampos-filippatos).

Comment: I couldn't catch you in chat yesterday. If you want leave a comment or an answer otherwise we'll chat tonight if we are both available.